# What is the default server characterset in mariadb inside the Swisscom Cloud and how can it be changed?

Tags: mariadb, swisscomdev

This is a request for clarification concerning the Swisscom Cloud MariaDB Service. This is not about the generic [MariaDB default charactersets](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-character-sets-and-collations/).

1. I would like to know what the default [`character_set_server`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#character_set_server) for the MariaDB Service on the Swisscom Cloud is defined as.
2. Assuming that it is actually `latin1`, I would like to know if this default can be changed (to `utf-8` or more accurately `utf8mb4` as it is for the [`debian mariadb package`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/differences-in-mariadb-in-debian-and-ubuntu)).

*The main reason for my question is that I am having trouble creating backups that can easily be re-imported and I am getting widely different size output when extracting via `mysqldump ... -r backup.sql` compared to an export through `Sequel Pro`.*

Comment: Do you want just the _default_ changed?  Or do you want to change all the data encoding, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use the tool `Sequel Pro`.

The legacy MariaDB/Galera cluster uses `latin1` as default character set when you don't set it. This default setting is from upstream MariaDB developers. Most developers and DBAs don't like this decision.

Here is the `CREATE TABLE` syntax (see `COLLATE` and `CHARACTER SET`) :

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (column_list)
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [COLLATE collation_name]]
```

Server settings (this statement can every customer execute, no admin rights needed):

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show global variables like 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                               |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                              |
| character_set_connection | latin1                              |
| character_set_database   | latin1                              |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                              |
| character_set_results    | latin1                              |
| character_set_server     | latin1                              |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mariadb-galera/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you still use legacy MariaDB, **please hurry up and [migrate your service instance](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/migrate-mariadb-to-mariadbent.html)**. The legacy cluster will be in one or two days read-only.

> We have a completely new MariaDB service in store for you. It comes
>   with many improvements (e.g. MariaDB version 10) and we recommend to
>   upgrade as soon as possible.

This step-by-step guide was created [Aug 16, 2017](https://github.com/swisscom/docs-appcloud-service-offerings/commit/676df4f26730d6213d4aecfd32b65c5a71ea1ae2).

The new cluster uses better default settings:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show global variables like 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                                                    |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                                                     |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                                                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                                                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                                                   |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                                                     |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                                                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                                                     |
| character_sets_dir       | /var/vcap/data/packages/mariadb/95a1896c4bcdccb4e1abd81b7d00eb33aedb0da0/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you wish to change your character set and collation before importing the data into new cluster.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [COLLATE collation_name]
```

We did this many times. Please keep in mind that you shouldn't do this with > 20000 records.

Please also have a look at our [documentation for MariaDB](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/mariadb.html)

> Please contact Swisscom Application Cloud support when you need to
>   issue long running DDL changes (for example `ALTER TABLE` with thousends
>   of records). Long running DDL causes an outage for all customers on
>   the cluster.

Comment: Great to see that the new MariaDB is UTF-8 by default - we already did the switch but had issues when restoring backups which seem to be related to a mix of charsets

Comment: Well...  MySQL's `utf8` is a subset of `UTF-8`.  It would be better to go all the way to `utf8mb4`.

Comment: That `ALTER` does not do anything other than change the _default_ for newly added columns !.  See `ALTER ... CONVERT TO ...` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is to demonstrate two different `ALTERs`; one does nothing useful; one does what you want:

-- Try the 'wrong' ALTER:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS atc;
    CREATE TABLE atc ( c VARCHAR(11))  CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
    INSERT INTO atc (c) VALUES ('ÃÔäô');
    SHOW CREATE TABLE atc\G
    SELECT c, HEX(c) FROM atc;   -- note the latin1 encoding
    ALTER TABLE atc CHARACTER SET utf8;
    SHOW CREATE TABLE atc\G   -- the column stays latin1, overriding the table
    SELECT c, HEX(c) FROM atc;   -- still latin1 encoding

mysql> 
mysql> -- Try the 'wrong' ALTER:
mysql> 
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS atc;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE atc ( c VARCHAR(11))  CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO atc (c) VALUES ('ÃÔäô');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE atc\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: atc
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `atc` (
  `c` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT c, HEX(c) FROM atc;   -- note the latin1 encoding
+----------+----------+
| c        | HEX(c)   |
+----------+----------+
| ÃÔäô     | C3D4E4F4 |
+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE atc CHARACTER SET utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE atc\G   -- the column stays latin1, overriding the table
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: atc
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `atc` (
  `c` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT c, HEX(c) FROM atc;   -- still latin1 encoding
+----------+----------+
| c        | HEX(c)   |
+----------+----------+
| ÃÔäô     | C3D4E4F4 |
+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- Try the 'right' way:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS atc;
    CREATE TABLE atc ( c VARCHAR(11))  CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
    INSERT INTO atc (c) VALUES ('ÃÔäô');
    SHOW CREATE TABLE atc\G
    SELECT c, HEX(c) FROM atc;   -- note the latin1 encoding
    ALTER TABLE atc CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
    SHOW CREATE TABLE atc\G   -- column and table are utf8
    SELECT c, HEX(c) FROM atc;   -- now utf8

mysql> 
mysql> -- Try the 'right' way:
mysql> 
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS atc;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE atc ( c VARCHAR(11))  CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO atc (c) VALUES ('ÃÔäô');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE atc\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: atc
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `atc` (
  `c` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT c, HEX(c) FROM atc;   -- note the latin1 encoding
+----------+----------+
| c        | HEX(c)   |
+----------+----------+
| ÃÔäô     | C3D4E4F4 |
+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE atc CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE atc\G   -- column and table are utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: atc
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `atc` (
  `c` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT c, HEX(c) FROM atc;   -- now utf8
+----------+------------------+
| c        | HEX(c)           |
+----------+------------------+
| ÃÔäô     | C383C394C3A4C3B4 |
+----------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```